# Problems with mi PATH "-bash: ls: command not found" help please :)

Tags: python, bash, command-line, terminal, path

I'm trying to work with my terminal and as I move from directories and try to list where I am I'm getting this message:

```
-bash: ls: command not found
```

I'm working on my macOS High Sierra, version 10.13.4 and here is what my .bash_profile has:

```
export PATH="/Users/trinidadbosch/Library/Python/3.9/bin:PATH"
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH


# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

alias python="python3" 
alias pip="pip3"


# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH


# >>> conda initialize >>>
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: should be ${PATH} or $PATH.  If it's PATH you'll lose all the other important path components, including wherever `ls` is defined

Comment: Thanks! should be "${PATH} or $PATH." On which line of the code? I'm quite new with coding and I get lost very often.

Comment: The first line should be `export PATH="/Users/trinidadbosch/Library/Python/3.9/bin:$PATH"` (note the `$` in front of the `PATH` at the end, but not the one near the beginning).

Comment: Sweet! It worked, thanks!!